# No input upon boot

Tags: drivers, safe-mode, blank-screen

Firstly, I know many people have this problem, but none of them seem to be the same situation as me. I just installed a new graphics card, and a new power supply. Once I had everything connected, I booted up windows fine. I than rebooted, activating a program called softXpand. I want to remove this program, but that's aside the point. The real problem is whenever I try to boot up my computer now, it will show the windows icon and right when it plays the startup sound, my screen goes blank. I double and tripple checked all the cables, and did not open my computer up between the first and broken startups. Also, when I try to boot in safe mode, it stops loading at CLASSPNP.sys.

I think this may be an issue with drivers but am far from 100%, does anyone know why this is happening, and maby how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May we assume you are running win 7 and not xp which appear to be the two versions of softXpand?  Please edit your question to clarify this.  Also it might be good to know which version of that os.  There is very little info at the softXpand site.  Can you tell us anything more you know about softXpand?

Comment: We'll thanks, but I fixed it, did a little fiddling and got it started in safe mode. With a bit of research I got it uninstalled (softXpand) and everything is fine now. Should save listened to my dad when he thought it was fishy.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> I fixed it, did a little fiddling and got it started in safe mode. With a bit of research I got it uninstalled (softXpand) and everything is fine now. Should save listened to my dad when he thought it was fishy.